# Как сохранить настройки в gnome-alsamixer?

Tags: ubuntu

В gnome-alsamixer ставлю галочку на "Headphone", и звук есть. Перезагружаю компьютер - звука нет. Захожу в gnome-alsamixer - галочка на "Headphone" не стоит. В консольном варианте alsamixer headphone поменять не получается.

Что можно сделать?

**UDP:** Забыл добавить, звука нет на передней панели. С заднего входа звук есть и без галочек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вероятно, вам стоит установить пакет *alsa-utils*, в составе которого [имеются и необходимые](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/alsa-utils/filelist) для сохранения и восстановления состояния *alsa* скрипты и конфигурационные файлы (для всего зоопарка систем инициализации, которые можно встретить в дистрибутивах *ubuntu*: sysvinit, upstart, systemd).

фактически этими скриптами должны будут выполняться (от имени *root-а*) команды:

- при загрузке: `alsactl restore`
- при перезагрузке или завершении работы: `alsactl store`

Comment: Не помогло. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: так это и есть единственный и возможный вариант сохранения/восстановления настроек alsa. если вручную настройки сохраняются/восстанавливаются, то разбирайтесь с упомянутым пакетом. если нет, то пишите баг в баг-трекер убунты.

Comment: Пакета до этого не было. Установил, перезагрузил ПК - ничего полезного. Получается, иду в баг-трекер.

Comment: если вручную не сохраняются/восстанавливаются (команды я привёл в ответе), то, да — путь лежит в баг-трекер.